# How to pull data from Firebase as a string in Dart?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I have a question about Firebase in Dart/Flutter. I have looked everywhere, and looked at this problem for a long time, but still can't figure it out, so decided to ask you guys.

I want to show my firebase data as a string. So I wanted to make a profile constructor, which gets the firebase data and stores them in an array list. That way, I can easily reference the firebase data as "widget.male.name", if I wanted to display the name. But, I am having some trouble with the array part. Here is my code:

```
    import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

final List<Male> demoProfiles = [
  new Male(
    photos: [
      'assets/photo_1.jpg',
      'assets/photo_2.jpg',
      'assets/photo_3.jpg',
      'assets/photo_4.jpg',
    ],
    name: 'Someone Special',
    description: 'This is the person you want!',
  ),
  new Male(
    photos: [
      'assets/photo_4.jpg',
      'assets/photo_3.jpg',
      'assets/photo_2.jpg',
      'assets/photo_1.jpg',
    ],
    name: 'Gross Person',
    description: 'You better swipe left...',
  ),
];
class Male {
  String key;
  String name;
  String description;
  String preference;

  Male(this.name, this.description, this.preference);

  Male.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot)
      : key = snapshot.key,
        name = snapshot.value["name"],
        preference = snapshot.value["preference"],
        description= snapshot.value["description"];

  toJson() {
    return {
      "name": name,
      "description": description,
      "preference": preference,
    };
  }
}
```

If you look at line 11, this is where I declare the name and description of the user. Now, I will see a string of "Someone Special", but I want to display the users name here. I am using a realtime database.

I often see people write "$name" when getting the name, but this isn't working either. I have also tried "datasnapshot.value", but that also isn't working. I want to take the value of the key and display it in a text object (I think it's called an object?).

Thanks in advance, and I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Unfortunatly there are no line numbers in stackoverflow and I only got 10 fingers so I was unable to find line 11.

Comment: Sorry, I originally had it in pastebin. I am talking about the line that says:

    name: 'Someone Special',